# Synchronized block - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I realize that the synchronized block provided in Java is basically an implementation of a re-entrant mutex. However is the synchronized block atomic?

So how are interrupts handled for threads currently executing within the synchronized block - does it simply release the lock by reverting all the changes made so far?

EDIT: With regards to the Interrupts part of the question - how is it generally handled in Java. For instance, I see many java code examples wherein developers catch an interrupt when (say) a thread is in the wait queue. However within the catch block all they do is print that an interrupt has been raised. I am more curious as to what actually happens to that thread? Is it removed from the wait queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-- atomicity

Synchronized blocks help to implement atomicity - but their data operations can't be garaunteed to be atomic. To make the stuff in a synchronized block atomic, you use often use atomic data structures like getters and setters, for example, AtomicBoolean.

There are a cornucopia of great atomic classes, like atomic int arrays, supported by the latest java version.

-- how interrupts are handled :

Interrupts are not explicitly handled by synchronization - synchronous blocks only gaurantee that, while executing, the block cannot be reentered by another thread.

Answer (score 2):

> However is the synchronized block atomic?

Yes, a synchronized block enforces that this block and any block that is synchronized on the same Object are atomic.

> How interrupts are handled:

Interrupts are completely different to synchronization in Java. Each Thread has an [`interruptedStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) flag that is set whenever you call [`interrupt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on the Thread. Methods such as `Thread.sleep()` throw an InterruptedException if the interrupt flag is set and halt their sleeping.

Note that `Thread.sleep()` does not relinquish any locks during the sleep period. The lock associated with a synchronized block is only released when the execution flows out of the block.

Comment: So basically it is upto a programmer to catch the Interrupt event and relinquish the lock in case its inside the synchronized block ?

Comment: @Titan The synchronized block is more equivalent to a scoped lock, so relinquishing the lock is done simply by leaving that scope. Note that interrupt events are simply a mechanism for low level Thread control - while they might be used at similar times they are orthogonal concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically it is upto a programmer to catch the Interrupt event and
>   relinquish the lock in case its inside the synchronized block ?

You do not have to handle the lock. As written in the [JLS 14.18](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#255769) **The synchronized Statement**:

> If execution of the Block completes normally, then the lock is
>   unlocked and the synchronized statement completes normally. If
>   execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the
>   lock is unlocked and the synchronized statement then completes
>   abruptly for the same reason.